# Highcharts standalone framework with highcharts-ng, angular. Animation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts

When I use the standalone framework for highcharts, the animation is faulty when I update the data. Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/user1572526/3stqK/3/ This error only occurs when I use the standalone framework. If I use the full jQuery library, it works. Has it something to do with the highcharts directive I'm using? https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng

Any idea how I can fix this? I really want to avoid dragin in the full jQuery library cause of this.

Highcharts with standalone framework. Animation works if I change to jquery.

```
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/master/js/adapters/standalone-framework.src.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem is with your additioanl plugin highcharts-ng, because without that, all works properly as in the example

```
var btn = document.getElementById('button'),
        y=30;

    btn.onclick = function(){
       chart.series[0].data[0].update(100);
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3stqK/5/